# Currency Conversion - Getting an equivalent % of currency outside of z/y pair

Tags: divisibility, economics

I am working with 3 currencies. I am trying to get a value (price of Y per Z) that is less 39X.

Let me elaborate with an example.

3% of 1300X = (**39 X**). I want to take 39X away from the Z/Y pair.

The information I do have:

**1.40510848 Z is worth 8432 Y**. 
**8432 Y and 1.405 Z both equal 295X**.

**Current price of each Y = 0.00016591 Z.**

**1 Z= 210.47 X**

Will this calculation work 295 X - 39 X = 256 X = 1.21 Z(I can get the conversion of X to Z easily)/8432 Y = 0.00014350094

And 0.00014350094 is where i'd set my stop loss? Is the difference between 0.000016591 Y - 0.00014350094 Y equivalent to taking 39X from 295X?

What I really want is to make sure I don't lose more than 3% of my total funds in X on any one trade. I only have the option of setting the stop loss in currency Y however, which is how much Y is worth per Z.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is almost impossible to read; it's not clear, first, whether $X$ and $Y$ denote amounts or currency names. When you say "$3\%$ of $1300$" ... that's not a risk limit, it's a number. A risk limit should be a value, i.e., some amount of some currency.  Look at your last sentence "I [can only set] the stop loss in currency Y, which is how much Y is worth per Z". What does "which" refer to? Currency Y? Stop loss? Neither can be "what Y is worth per Z"--one's a currency, the other's an amount. Suppose we make this concrete: what's the phrase "what USD is worth per Yen" mean?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I tried to make it a little clearer Y Z X are all currencies like yea. USD, YEN or AUD.